# Regex selecting carriage return at empty line

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
<pstyle:Chapter>LXXI
stuff
stuff

<pstyle:Chapter>LXXII
stuff
stuff

<pstyle:Chapter>LXXIII
stuff
stuff
```

And I want to select the text from the `<pstyle:Chapter>` tag down to the first empty line (including the carriage return), basically one full chapter at a time (I will change the roman numeral by hand each time).

I tried doing `\<pstyle\:Chapter\>LXXI.*\r` but it's not working.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Clarification: I'm using TextWrangler (PCRE)

Comment: It seems unlikely that you would have a carriage return `\r` but _not_ a newline `\n`.

Comment: I tried `\r\n` but I get no matches.

Comment: Try just `\n`. To expound upon my previous comment, UNIX-based systems (including Mac OS X) use `\n` as end-of-line delimiters. Windows uses `\r\n`. Only earlier systems (e.g., Mac OS 9 and earlier) use `\r` with no linefeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex

```
^\<[^\>]+\>.*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iU2qX3)

Is what i'd switch to or

```
^\<pstyle\:Chapter\>.*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aV0rH3)

or

```
^\<pstyle\:Chapter\>LXXI.*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aI1zY5)

Comment: Asker wants to capture multiple lines.

Comment: @Wiseguy just adding `gms` to the flags resolves this.  unless he is using javascript regex engine.

Comment: This selects all three chapters, I need to select just one.

Comment: @DiegoR You could modify that to 1) be a lazy quantifier `.*?`, and 2) have a terminating condition between chapters (back to back end-of-lines).  http://regex101.com/r/sG1oN7

Comment: It works on regex101.com but not on my text (it selects only the chapter line), so there must be something between the chapter line and the end CR that's preventing it from working. (the "stuff" lines represent hundreds of lines of text with all sorts of alphanumeric & symbol characters).

Comment: @DiegoR Okay, instead of trying to match whatever end-of-line might be available, what if you just had a lookahead for the next `<pstyle:Chapter>`? ( http://regex101.com/r/fA7gT4 ) That avoids `\r` and `\n` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Wiseguy, you probably want `\n`. Check this out: http://regex101.com/r/cZ8qG6